# Birthday Calculator

Tags: php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Birthday </title>

<?php

    if(isset($_POST["birthday"]))
        $birthday = $_POST["birthday"];
    else
        $birthday = 1;

    function calculate_age($birthday){

        list($day, $month , $year) = explode("/", $birthday);
        $day_diff = date("d") - $day;
        $month_diff = date("m") - $month;
        $year_diff = date("Y") - $year;
        if($month_diff < 0){
            $year_diff--;
        }
        else if(($month_diff == 0) && ($day_diff < 0)){
             $year_diff--;
        }
        else if (($month_diff == 0) && ($day_diff == 0)){
             echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Happy 
             Birthday!!!');</script>";
        }

         return $year_diff;
        }

        $finalBirthday=calculate_age($birthday);

 ?>

</head>
<body>

     <h1>Birthday Calculator</h1>

     <form name="Birthday" method="POST" action="birthday.php">
        <label>What is your Birthday?</br></label>
        <input type ="text" name = "birthday" VALUE = "DD/MM/YYYY"></br>
        <input type ="submit" name = "submit" VALUE = "Submit"></br>
     </form>

<?php

    echo "Our Birthday Calculator says you are " .$finalBirthday;

 ?> 

 </body>
 </html>
```

I was wondering why first running this it comes up with "Our Birthday Calculator says you are 2017".

After putting an actual date in, however, the php works properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: because `$birthday = 1;`. Use a Debugger or echo to see what the Content of  `$day_diff = date("d") - $day;` and so on is

Comment: Does the php `if else` statement work properly like that? never seen it like that before. if not using curly braces ive seen it used like     `if(isset($_POST["birthday"])):
        $birthday = $_POST["birthday"];
    else:
        $birthday = 1;
   endif;` note the `:` and final endif;

Answer (score 1):

Because the first time the code is run, $birthday is set to 1 and then passed through the calculate_age() function.

the function expects a string representation of a date separated by forward slashes /.

You aren't passing the function what it expects so it's returning gibberish.

Expanded solution: Don't do the calculation unless you have a date:

```
$finalBirthday = false;

if(isset($_POST["birthday"]))
    $birthday = $_POST["birthday"];

    list($day, $month , $year) = explode("/", $birthday);
    $day_diff = date("d") - $day;
    $month_diff = date("m") - $month;
    $year_diff = date("Y") - $year;
    if($month_diff < 0){
        $year_diff--;
    }
    else if(($month_diff == 0) && ($day_diff < 0)){
         $year_diff--;
    }
    else if (($month_diff == 0) && ($day_diff == 0)){
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Happy 
         Birthday!!!');</script>";
    }

    $finalBirthday=$year_diff;

}
```

...

```
<?php

    if ($finalBirthday) {
        echo "Our Birthday Calculator says you are " .$finalBirthday;
    }

 ?>
```

Comment: After messing around with some things I still haven't been able to fix it. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

well since birthday = 1 the day = 1 and month = null and year = null.

This would be somewhat equivalent to your birthday being 1/0/00 making you 2017 years old

Comment: After messing around with some things I still haven't been able to fix it. Any recommendations?

Comment: See my expanded answer